# How to match two Strings without considering spaces in php?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How to match two strings without considering spaces in `PHP`?

Example :
How to search **32GB** in below string?

```
$str='LeEco Le 2 (Grey, 32 GB)(3 GB RAM)';
```

Comment: why the title is about comparing strings?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: Because OP wants to check if the string contains `32GB`, and the expected result is true. A kind of a  "space-insensitive" search. However, the question is still not that clear.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, not comparing, it's called matching  `'LeEco Le 2 (Grey, 32 GB)(3 GB RAM)'`  against `32GB`  without considering spaces

Comment: [Remove the spaces](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) from both strings, use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to check if one of them is present into the other.

Comment: Hi @RomanPerekhrest,You are correct.My problem is  space-insensitive.Yes i want the result is true.

Comment: actually, the @axiac's advice would be enough to check the condition

Answer (score 3):

The following approach uses a kind of "fuzzy search" (eliminating whitespaces and converting the string to lowercase):

```
<?php

$str = 'LeEco Le 2 (Grey, 32 GB)(3 GB RAM)';

$regex = '~\d+\s*GB~';

$needle = '32gb';

if (preg_match($regex, $str, $match)) {
    $match = strtolower(preg_replace('~\s+~', '', $match[0]));
    if ($match == $needle) {
        echo "Found";
    }
}
```

Comment: HI,I am not sure the string only GB,also RAM etc...                                 $regex = '~\d+\s*GB~';

Comment: @user6559729: Then further clarify what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your response.How to remove space between  number and text ex:(32 GB,23 GOLD). I expect the result is :32GB,23GOLD like this method($regex = '~\d+\s*GB~')

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = preg_match("/(\d+)(\s*)GB/", $str);
```

If you want find "GB" as well as "gb", add the modifier "i" after the second slash.